# gksudo not caching credentials

Tags: sudo

I've built a shell script for [mounting ISO images](https://github.com/l0b0/mount-image) in Nautilus, and it worked fine in earlier versions of Ubuntu. One of the many problems encountered in 11.04 is that `gksudo` doesn't seem to cache the credentials - There are three commands in the script which need to be run as root, but now for every command I get prompted for a password. Sudo privileges are cached when using plain `sudo`, so why not with `gksudo`?

Comment: Share your /etc/sudoers please

Comment: @warl0ck: It's the [default `sudoers` delivered with Ubuntu 12.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers#The_Default_Ubuntu_Sudoers_File).